# Run Windows 7 over Linux without Intell VT support with free software

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualization

I have dual boot, and additionally I want to be able to run Windows 7 (that installed directly on hard disk) over Linux (CentOS 5.5), but my processor doesn't support Intel VT (hardware virtualization).
I try Xen, but it doesn't work because I think it may use only hardware virtualization.
Windows 7 is closed source, so I cannot use para-virtualization. So only thing is full virtualization (application virtualization, dynamic translation) but it seems to work very slowly and only tool I know for this is VMWare, but it proprietary and I want something free.

May you suggest my the best way to virtualize installed on hard disk Windows 7 on Linux with open source program?
Thank you for ahead.

Comment: what cpu do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) is free software (well, the free version is free) and should work in this case. There is also a zero-cost version based on free version on the same site.

Comment: @Rodnower You may want to reconsider  accepting this answer! At the moment I can't find a way to run system installed on HDD from VirutalBox. I heard that it was possible, but now that I decided to check, I can't see that option anywhere. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a VHD of the Windows 7 installation first in order to get it to work in VirtualBox.